# Is it possible for heat to warp a Unibody MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, damage, unibody

Inspired by this question: [Bulge in MacBook Pro near Hard drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/197697/123520)

Could the heat generated from a MacBook Pro (over a period of several hours running at around 100% CPU usage) warp an area of the Unibody shell?

Specifically- would this be a possibility if it was a Mid 2010 Unibody Case?